# How to translate this Python code to JavaScript? (involves Sets)

Tags: javascript, python

https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-duplicate-letters/description

> Given a string which contains only lowercase letters, remove duplicate
>   letters so that every letter appear once and only once. You must make
>   sure your result is the smallest in lexicographical order among all
>   possible results.
>
> Example:
>
> Given `"bcabc"`
>   Return `"abc"`
>
> Given `"cbacdcbc"` Return `"acdb"`

Python:

```
def removeDuplicateLetters(self, s):
    for c in sorted(set(s)):
        suffix = s[s.index(c):]
        if set(suffix) == set(s):
            return c + self.removeDuplicateLetters(suffix.replace(c, ''))
    return ''
```

The above is the correct solution, so I tried converting it to JavaScript.

```js
var removeDuplicateLetters = function(s) {
  for (var c of new Set(s.split('').sort())) {
    var suffix = s.substring(s.indexOf(c));
    if (setsAreEqual(new Set(suffix), new Set(s))) {
      return c + removeDuplicateLetters(suffix.replace(c, ''));
    }
  }
  return '';
};

const setsAreEqual = (a, b) => a.size === b.size && [...a].every(x => b.has(x));

console.log(removeDuplicateLetters("cbacdcbc"));
```

Which gives the wrong answer `acdbc` instead of `acdb`.

Where is the error in my translation?

Comment: `"".join(sorted((set("cbacdcbc"))))`   You can use one line in python to remove duplicates

Comment: @sailesh  I believe there is more to this question than just removing duplicate letters.   Otherwise the JS could just be -> `Array.from(new Set("cbacdcbc".split(""))).sort().join('')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript `replace` does not happen globally. It will only replace the first occurrence. Change the JavaScript to be 
`.replace(new RegExp(c, 'g'), '')`.